# Set description in paypal API (Client SITE)

Tags: javascript, api, paypal

I am trying to set a description for my payment. Code example:

```
    // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
    return actions.payment.create({
        payment: {

            transactions: [
                {
                    amount: { total: '<?= $amount / 100 ?>', currency: 'EUR' },
                    description: {'The payment transaction description.'}
                }
            ]
        }
    });
},
```

It does not work though. Currently got this example from here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

Can I set the description on the clientside? Without the description the payment works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `{` and `}` around the description string.

Comment: Then I get an error: Refused to get unsafe header "X-DEBUGKIT-ID" in the Browser Console - the window opens, but the payment won go through. Are you sure this works? Then I am looking for something else.

Comment: Is the description really the only difference between a case that works and one that doesn't? The error you quote seems to be completely unrelated.

Comment: Seems like the sandbox takes about 5-10 minuts to show the payment. I thinks that solved the problem. Thank you!